# can not install ruby-1.8.7-p249 on rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm

```
$ rvm install ruby-1.8.7-p249
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.8.7-p249 - #fetching 
ruby-1.8.7-p249 - #extracted to /home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249 (already extracted)
ruby-1.8.7-p249 - #configuring 
ruby-1.8.7-p249 - #compiling 
ERROR: Error running 'make ', please read /home/sayuj/.rvm/log/ruby-1.8.7-p249/make.log
ERROR: There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

**EDIT**

I use Ubuntu 11.10

`$ cat /home/sayuj/.rvm/log/ruby-1.8.7-p249/make.log`

```
[2011-10-17 15:34:49] make 
gcc -g -O2  -fPIC    -DRUBY_EXPORT -D_GNU_SOURCE=1  -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic   main.o  libruby-static.a -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -o miniruby
rbconfig.rb updated
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libruby.so.1.8   array.o bignum.o class.o compar.o dir.o dln.o enum.o enumerator.o error.o eval.o file.o gc.o hash.o inits.o io.o marshal.o math.o numeric.o object.o pack.o parse.o process.o prec.o random.o range.o re.o regex.o ruby.o signal.o sprintf.o st.o string.o struct.o time.o util.o variable.o version.o  dmyext.o -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -o libruby.so.1.8.7
compiling Win32API
compiling bigdecimal
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/bigdecimal'
gcc -shared -o ../../.ext/x86_64-linux/bigdecimal.so bigdecimal.o -L. -L../.. -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib -L/home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib -lruby  -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/bigdecimal'
compiling curses
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/curses'
gcc -shared -o ../../.ext/x86_64-linux/curses.so curses.o -L. -L../.. -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib -L/home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib -lruby -lncurses -ltinfo  -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/curses'
compiling dbm
compiling digest
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/digest'
gcc -shared -o ../../.ext/x86_64-linux/digest.so digest.o -L. -L../.. -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib -L/home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib -lruby  -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
cp ../.././ext/digest/digest.h ../../.ext/x86_64-linux
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/digest'
compiling digest/bubblebabble
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/digest/bubblebabble'
gcc -shared -o ../../../.ext/x86_64-linux/digest/bubblebabble.so bubblebabble.o -L. -L../../.. -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib -L/home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib -lruby  -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/digest/bubblebabble'
compiling digest/md5
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/digest/md5'
gcc -shared -o ../../../.ext/x86_64-linux/digest/md5.so md5init.o md5ossl.o -L. -L../../.. -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib -L/home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib -lruby -lcrypto  -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/digest/md5'
compiling digest/rmd160
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/digest/rmd160'
gcc -shared -o ../../../.ext/x86_64-linux/digest/rmd160.so rmd160init.o rmd160ossl.o -L. -L../../.. -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib -L/home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib -lruby -lcrypto  -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/digest/rmd160'
compiling digest/sha1
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/digest/sha1'
gcc -shared -o ../../../.ext/x86_64-linux/digest/sha1.so sha1init.o sha1ossl.o -L. -L../../.. -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib -L/home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib -lruby -lcrypto  -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/digest/sha1'
compiling digest/sha2
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/digest/sha2'
gcc -shared -o ../../../.ext/x86_64-linux/digest/sha2.so sha2.o sha2init.o -L. -L../../.. -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib -L/home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib -lruby  -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/digest/sha2'
compiling dl
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/dl'
gcc -shared -o ../../.ext/x86_64-linux/dl.so handle.o ptr.o dl.o sym.o -L. -L../.. -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib -L/home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib -lruby -ldl  -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
cp dlconfig.h ../../.ext/x86_64-linux
cp ../.././ext/dl/dl.h ../../.ext/x86_64-linux
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/dl'
compiling etc
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/etc'
gcc -shared -o ../../.ext/x86_64-linux/etc.so etc.o -L. -L../.. -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib -L/home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib -lruby  -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/etc'
compiling fcntl
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/fcntl'
gcc -shared -o ../../.ext/x86_64-linux/fcntl.so fcntl.o -L. -L../.. -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib -L/home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib -lruby  -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/fcntl'
compiling gdbm
compiling iconv
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/iconv'
gcc -shared -o ../../.ext/x86_64-linux/iconv.so iconv.o -L. -L../.. -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib -L/home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib -lruby  -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/iconv'
compiling io/wait
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/io/wait'
gcc -shared -o ../../../.ext/x86_64-linux/io/wait.so wait.o -L. -L../../.. -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib -L/home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib -lruby  -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/io/wait'
compiling nkf
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/nkf'
gcc -shared -o ../../.ext/x86_64-linux/nkf.so nkf.o -L. -L../.. -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib -L/home/sayuj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib -lruby  -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/nkf'
compiling openssl
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/openssl'
gcc -I. -I../.. -I../../. -I../.././ext/openssl -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"    -fPIC -g -O2  -fPIC   -c ossl_pkcs7.c
ossl_pkcs7.c: In function ‘ossl_pkcs7si_new’:
ossl_pkcs7.c:89:5: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘ASN1_dup’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/openssl/asn1.h:955:7: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void **, const unsigned char **, long int)’ but argument is of type ‘char * (*)()’
ossl_pkcs7.c: In function ‘DupPKCS7SignerPtr’:
ossl_pkcs7.c:102:5: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘ASN1_dup’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/openssl/asn1.h:955:7: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void **, const unsigned char **, long int)’ but argument is of type ‘char * (*)()’
ossl_pkcs7.c: In function ‘ossl_pkcs7ri_new’:
ossl_pkcs7.c:115:5: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘ASN1_dup’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/openssl/asn1.h:955:7: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void **, const unsigned char **, long int)’ but argument is of type ‘char * (*)()’
ossl_pkcs7.c: In function ‘DupPKCS7RecipientPtr’:
ossl_pkcs7.c:128:5: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘ASN1_dup’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/openssl/asn1.h:955:7: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void **, const unsigned char **, long int)’ but argument is of type ‘char * (*)()’
ossl_pkcs7.c: At top level:
ossl_pkcs7.c:573:1: error: unknown type name ‘STACK’
ossl_pkcs7.c: In function ‘pkcs7_get_certs_or_crls’:
ossl_pkcs7.c:593:15: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
ossl_pkcs7.c:596:31: warning: pointer type mismatch in conditional expression [enabled by default]
ossl_pkcs7.c: In function ‘ossl_pkcs7_set_certificates’:
ossl_pkcs7.c:611:11: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
ossl_pkcs7.c: In function ‘ossl_pkcs7_get_certificates’:
ossl_pkcs7.c:621:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘ossl_x509_sk2ary’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
ossl.h:121:7: note: expected ‘struct stack_st_X509 *’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
ossl_pkcs7.c: In function ‘ossl_pkcs7_set_crls’:
ossl_pkcs7.c:651:10: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
ossl_pkcs7.c: In function ‘ossl_pkcs7_get_crls’:
ossl_pkcs7.c:661:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘ossl_x509crl_sk2ary’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
ossl.h:122:7: note: expected ‘struct stack_st_X509_CRL *’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
make[1]: *** [ossl_pkcs7.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sayuj/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/openssl'
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is the first ruby install or have others worked ok?  Which OS?  If OSX, do you have gcc or XCode installed?  Is there anything in the log file - /home/sayuj/.rvm/log/ruby-1.8.7-p249/make.log ?

Comment: i use ubuntu 11.10. edited the question. i can not understand anything from the log file!

Comment: Ok - do you have the gcc/build dependancies installed?  Please post the log file into your question - perhaps someone here will understand it :)   There is usually an error towards the end, say the last 50 lines or so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem is:

```
ossl_pkcs7.c:573:1: error: unknown type name ‘STACK’
```

My guess is its a dependancy issue.

Look at the output of:

```
rvm notes
```

And ensure you have followed all the steps for Ubuntu.

One obvious thing is that Ubuntu 11.10 is only just out - might be worth searching/posting on the Ubuntu forums to see if anyone there has had any issues with it and rvm.

Answer (score 5):

From here : http://ahmy.yulrizka.com/2011/10/ruby-ree-1-8-7-openssl-error/

```
rvm pkg install openssl
```

And from one of the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8544958/178975

```
rvm install ruby-1.8.7 --with-openssl-dir=<rvm_dir>/usr
```

where rvm_dir could be $HOME/.rvm or /usr/local/rvm or wherever you have installed rvm

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to install ruby with rvm and giving the open-ssl-dir explicitly like this:

```
rvm cleanup
rvm install ruby-1.8.7 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```