# RVM + ruby 1.9.3-p286

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

Just tried to install ruby 1.9.3-p286 on osx 10.8.2 using RVM and received the following errors:

```
Installing new ruby ruby-1.9.3-p286
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #configure
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #download
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #extract
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #validate

Libraries missing for ruby-1.9.3-p286: /opt/sm/pkg/versions/libffi/3.0.10/lib/libffi.5.dylib. Refer to your system manual for installing libraries

Mounting remote ruby failed, trying to compile.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/lee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p286, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p286 to /Users/lee/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p286
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #extracted to /Users/lee/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p286
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #configuring
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #compiling
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #installing

Error running 'make install', please read /Users/lee/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p286/install.log
There has been an error while running make install. Halting the installation.
```

I've googled for these errors but nothing has helped so far, any help is appreciated.

Comment: What’s in `/Users/lee/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p286/install.log`?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/3921177

Comment: please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792105/can-not-install-ruby-1-8-7-p249-on-rvm  They had the same issue

Comment: strange, I can install 1.9.3-p194 without issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this should be fixed with https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1244 - the issue should be already fixed:

```
rvm get head
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```