# Trying to install Ruby 1.8.7-p249 on Ubuntu 16 results in an SSL error

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, openssl, rvm, ruby-1.8.7

There's a lot of questions regarding this on Stackoverflow, but the answers appear to be out of date or not applicable to my situation.

I've followed the instructions in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9440944/1446264

And after running

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm install ruby-1.8.7-p249 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/share/rvm/usr
```

I'm still left with the following error on the server.

```
make[1]: *** [ossl.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/share/rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-
p249/ext/openssl'
make: *** [all] Error 1`
```

I think the reason must be because the version of openssl installed after running `rvm pkg install openssl` is too new.

`openssl version`  gives me `1.0.1f`

and

`rvm pkg install openssl` installed `openssl-1.0.1i`

On my development machine, I'm running `openssl-0.9.8zh` without any issues, so ideally I'd like to be able to use this version of openssl.

Is there any way of specifying a version number when running `rvm pkg install openssl`? so I could do something like `rvm pkg install openssl -v 0.9.8zh`. I've not come across any such syntax.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can resolve this? I've been battling for hours. I've tried installing Ruby from source as well as with RVM and Rbenv but the openssl issue persists.

Comment: Why such an old Ruby version?

Comment: I’d be remiss if I didn’t mention that Ruby 1.8.7 is ancient, unsupported, and contains numerous un-patched security vulnerabilities. You should upgrade your application to work on a newer, supported Ruby if possible. Further, OpenSSL 0.9.x is *also* unsupported, and likely contains numerous un-patched vulnerabilities.

Comment: It's not my decision. It's a large, old Rails 2 application, and I've been given the task of getting it setup on a new server.